# Why is the fragment_main.xml missing in the ADT Bundle 20140702?

Tags: android, eclipse

According to the instructions that [Building a Simple User Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#) on the website of Android Developers, I am goint to open the fragment_main.xml file from the res/layout/ directory with the Eclipse.
But based on the ADT Bundle 20140702, there is only the activity_main.xml in the res/layout.
Or fragment_main.xml can be found on the version 20140321.

Comment: The ADT Bundle 20140321 would generate fragment_main.xml in the res/layout/ directory automatically,but the 20140702 version would not.Is it true?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what IDE you are using, creating a fragment layout for your main activity may only be an option now. If my memory serves me correctly I believe the automatically created fragment was prevalent in all IDEs at the time that tutorial was written.

Just use activity_main.xml instead of this fragment_main.xml and the tutorial will work fine.
OR you can also right-click on the layout folder and create a new XML layout file and name it fragment_main.xml

Answer (score 1):

By default when you make a new Android app project on yours ecclipse IDE , the default layout name is -

```
activity_main.xml
```

Which is a blank xml layout .

So you need to code yours `fragment_main.xml` under   `res/layout/` directory  , as per yours implementation chosen at **Android developers** page

steps - 
right click `res/layout/` > choose **new** > **new android xml file** > give the file name as **fragment_main.xml**  and write yours code in it

or

just right click activity_main.xml > **refactor** > **rename** to **fragment_main.xml**

Answer (score 1):

While creating the new android application project,choose "**Blank Activity with Fragment**" option on the page "Create Activity". Then, we can find the **fragment_main.xml**.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new `fragment_main.xml` file as per above but make sure in the `MainActivity.java` you change this line of code:
from
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
to
`setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);`